# How can I create two LongListSelector combined and scroll together?

Tags: windows-phone-8, scrollview, longlistselector

I have two different list and a title between them. How can I combine all of those and add them into a scrollview? Should I create all of my items and add them to a grid dynamically or is there a way that I can combine those with longlistselector?

Here is a pic of what I want to create:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Updated Solution

---

How about a `<ScrollViewer>` and two (2) `<ItemControl>` instead like so:  Then set the ItemControl's ItemsSource to what ever list you have.

```XAML
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel>                    
        <!-- list #1 -->
        <ItemsControl x:Name="list1" ItemsSource="{Binding YOURLIST_1}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding YOURTEXT}"></TextBlock>
                        <!-- ................ -->
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>                    
        <!-- header -->
        <TextBlock Text="YOUR HEADER"></TextBlock>
        <!-- list #2 -->
        <ItemsControl x:Name="list2" ItemsSource="{Binding YOURLIST_2}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding YOURTEXT}"></TextBlock>
                        <!-- ................ -->
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

---

*OLD Solution*

That would be very difficult to do and probably very cumbersome. But it seems like you can achieve the same result with **ONE** `LongListSelector` if you were to Group your model items using a Key.

---

[How to display data in a grouped list in `LongListSelector` for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj244365%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Your "Header" will become your Key.  Launch the Windows Phone News app, under the "Headlines" page you will see a good example of Grouping.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer but the link that you provided is using one model for items. In my project, I have two different models. Can I still achieve that with grouping?

Comment: @FigenGüngör okay, you should of mention that before hand :), how about a scroll view and 2 itemcontols instead. :D, check edited solution.